# javascript change name of id element

Tags: javascript

I've got a form which display's an input field in a for loop in php.  It is a date field.  So if the user clicks on the date field I want it to automatically input today's date.  The problem I am having since I don't really know javascript is my input fields' name in php changes everytime in the for loop to myText1, myText2, etc., how do I change it in javascript? (Eg. document.getElementById("myText1"), document.getElementById("myText2")

Form Field

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
    echo '<td><font size="1"><input id="myText' . $x . '" name="myText' . $x . '"' . ' type="text" value="" onClick="myFunction()"/></font></td>';
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why not assign your inputs with a class name? You can loop through the class or you can use another for loop in javascript, limit to 15 and use `document.getElementById("myText"+x)`

Comment: And don't use the `font` element. It is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind same input using **this**

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
    echo '<td><font size="1"><input id="myText' . $x . '" name="myText' . $x . '"' . ' type="text" value="" onClick="myFunction(this)"/></font></td>';
}
```

**Script**

```
<script>
function myFunction(obj) {
        obj.value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You pass a reference to the element into the function. In the `onclick`, you have that reference as `this`, so:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
    echo '<td><font size="1"><input id="myText' . $x . '" name="myText' . $x . '"' . ' type="text" value="" onClick="myFunction(this)"/></font></td>';
    // >>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
}
```

Then

```
function myFunction(element) {
    element.value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the answer, and also the reference to Johnny Bravo. A great TV show indeed :)

Comment: @JasonEvans: :-) That was the OP, I merely copied and pasted it.

Comment: Oh, missed that. Well kudos to the OP also :)

Answer (score 2):

Premising that you should avoid to define inline event handlers and mix server-side code with markup, you could pass `this` parameter to the function you call at the `click` event

```
...onclick="myFunction(this)"
```

then use it as an argument inside your function

```
<script>
function myFunction(t) {
    t.value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass id in your `myFunction()`

```
echo '<td><font size="1"><input id="myText' . $x . '" name="myText' . $x . '"' . ' type="text" value="" onClick="myFunction(this)"/></font></td>';

<script>
function myFunction(uid) {
    document.getElementById(uid).value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why pass the `id` rather than the element, just to turn around and look up the element using the id?

Answer (score 1):

ich would prefer to set a class for each input element you want to change by focus e.g. and bind an event for these types.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="click me" class="change_js"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="click me" class="change_js"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="click me" class="change_js"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the javascript code

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('change_js')

for (var i = 0, len=elements.length;i<len;i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('focus',function(){
    this.value="Johnny Bravo";
  })

}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/19uqca7z/

for detailed information about javascript code:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

use the below code in your javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    this.value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
</script>
```

Now your function is independent of what you give in PHP code, `this` variable will always refers to the element that was clicked